# How do I fix a non-recoverable error in pgAdmin4

Tags: database, backend, render

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEmuA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DneaR.png)

When attempting to create, setup and connect my postgres database (pgAdmin4) through Render to be able to deploy the backend for my project. But I recieve an error that reads "Unable to connect to server: connection is bad: - A non-recoverable error occured during a database lookup"

I have looked through pgAdmin4 documentation for this error but the documentation does not show this error at all ( https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/connect_error.html ). I have tried switching between the external and internal URL's as well as the hostname but nothing seems to be working. Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance.